# How to find frequency of occurances of a certain condition in python

Tags: python, count

I have the following dataset:

```
{
    "checkpoint_size": 89453.0,
    "resource_id": "0c8b6b26",
    "timetamp": "2015-07-08T10:53:33"
}{
    "checkpoint_size": 89453.0,
    "resource_id": "d36f2527",
    "timetamp": "2015-07-08T10:53:33"
}{
    "checkpoint_size": 89453.0,
    "resource_id": "0c8b6b26",
    "timetamp": "2015-07-08T10:53:33"
}{
    "checkpoint_size": 89453.0,
    "resource_id": "d36f2527",
    "timetamp": "2015-07-08T10:43:33"
}{
    "checkpoint_size": 89453.0,
    "resource_id": "0c8b6b26",
    "timetamp": "2015-07-08T10:43:33"
}{
    "checkpoint_size": 89453.0,
    "resource_id": "d36f2527",
    "timetamp": "2015-07-08T10:43:33"
}{
    "checkpoint_size": 5000.0,
    "resource_id": "0c8b6b26",
    "timetamp": "2015-07-08T10:43:33"
}{
    "checkpoint_size": 5000.0,
    "resource_id": "d36f2527",
    "timetamp": "2015-07-08T10:33:33"
}
```

I want to find the number of times checkpoint_size < 10240 which is 2 times in the given dataset. How can I implement this in python?

my code right now is

```
data_checkpoint_size = cclient.samples.list(meter_name ='checkpoint.size')


checkpoint_size_limit = 10240

def counterVolume(data_checkpoint_size):
  for each in data_checkpoint_size:
        x = each.counter_volume
        y = each.timestamp
        z = each.resource_id[<OldSample {u'counter_name': u'cpu_util', u'user_id': u'7bffa12f482840c7801e3e01e160c8cb', u'resource_id': u'ef392c3d-74fa-43fe-87c5-7e117b6d8a09', u'timestamp': u'2015-07-01T15:13:55', u'counter_volume': 0.034999999999999996, u'resource_metadata': {u'ramdisk_id': u'None', u'flavor.vcpus': u'1', u'OS-EXT-AZ.availability_zone': u'nova', u'display_name': u'ubuntu-io', u'flavor.id': u'596642d8-0813-4ae9-aec4-0105fdf05761', u'status': u'active', u'ephemeral_gb': u'0', u'flavor.name': u'm1.small.io', u'disk_gb': u'20', u'kernel_id': u'None', u'image.id': u'5776a360-0953-4c93-931d-a6e3616fb8dc', u'flavor.ram': u'2048', u'host': u'9fa544f5c47569db21d50bc6c0765296316a56bd6baf6b04d705686a', u'flavor.ephemeral': u'0', u'image.name': u'ubuntu-io', u'image_ref_url': u'link': u"[{'href': 'link', 'rel': 'bookmark'}]", u'cpu_number': u'1', u'flavor.disk': u'20', u'root_gb': u'20', u'name': u'instance-000000d3', u'memory_mb': u'2048', u'instance_type': u'596642d8-0813-4ae9-aec4-0105fdf05761', u'vcpus': u'1', u'image_ref': u'5776a360-0953-4c93-931d-a6e3616fb8dc', u'flavor.links': u"[{'href': 'link', 'rel': 'bookmark'}]"}, u'source': u'openstack', u'counter_unit': u'%', u'recorded_at': u'2015-07-01T15:13:56.006000', u'project_id': u'1670f0e56fb6421cb83d81b60b149c04', u'message_id': u'ca8ea466-2003-11e5-a764-002590e64886', u'counter_type': u'gauge'}>, <OldSample {u'counter_name': u'cpu_util', u'user_id': u'7bffa12f482840c7801e3e01e160c8cb', u'resource_id': u'0c8b6b26-3340-41e3-ac8b-cc38f15d3570', u'timestamp': u'2015-07-01T15:08:32', u'counter_volume': 5.4399999999999995, u'resource_metadata': {u'ramdisk_id': u'None', u'flavor.vcpus': u'1', u'OS-EXT-AZ.availability_zone': u'nova', u'display_name': u'kalman_instance', u'flavor.id': u'1', u'status': u'active', u'ephemeral_gb': u'0', u'flavor.name': u'm1.tiny', u'disk_gb': u'1', u'kernel_id': u'None', u'image.id': u'1c9b08f0-d1fa-4acc-a11c-87b77310158c', u'flavor.ram': u'512', u'host': u'25aa71ded460ea9d4bf52e1aac34017691699cb5e4e389704d738bed', u'flavor.ephemeral': u'0', u'image.name': u'cirros', u'image_ref_url': u'http://192.168.26.1:8774/d1d65b6feab741a6a2905e6197cb15ee/images/1c9b08f0-d1fa-4acc-a11c-87b77310158c', u'image.links': u"[{'href': 'http://192.168.26.1:8774/d1d65b6feab741a6a2905e6197cb15ee/images/1c9b08f0-d1fa-4acc-a11c-87b77310158c', 'rel': 'bookmark'}]", u'cpu_number': u'1', u'flavor.disk': u'1', u'root_gb': u'1', u'name': u'instance-0000013c', u'memory_mb': u'512', u'instance_type': u'1', u'vcpus': u'1', u'image_ref': u'1c9b08f0-d1fa-4acc-a11c-87b77310158c', u'flavor.links': u"[{'href': 'http://192.168.26.1:8774/d1d65b6feab741a6a2905e6197cb15ee/flavors/1', 'rel': 'bookmark'}]"}, u'source': u'openstack', u'counter_unit': u'%', u'recorded_at': u'2015-07-01T15:08:32.459000', u'project_id': u'1670f0e56fb6421cb83d81b60b149c04', u'message_id': u'09b5173e-2003-11e5-ac7a-002590e64b12', u'counter_type': u'gauge'}>]
        with open('datae.txt', 'a') as outfile:
          json.dump({'checkpoint_size': x, 'timetamp': y, 'resource_id': z}, outfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

the raw data looks like this:

```
[<OldSample {u'counter_name': u'checkpoint_size', u'user_id': u'7bffa12f482840c7801e3e01e160c8cb', u'resource_id': u'ef392c3d-74fa-43fe-87c5-7e117b6d8a09', u'timestamp': u'2015-07-01T15:13:55', u'counter_volume': 0.034999999999999996, u'resource_metadata': {u'ramdisk_id': u'None', u'flavor.vcpus': u'1', u'OS-EXT-AZ.availability_zone': u'nova', u'display_name': u'ubuntu-io', u'flavor.id': u'596642d8-0813-4ae9-aec4-0105fdf05761', u'status': u'active', u'ephemeral_gb': u'0', u'flavor.name': u'm1.small.io', u'disk_gb': u'20', u'kernel_id': u'None', u'image.id': u'5776a360-0953-4c93-931d-a6e3616fb8dc', u'flavor.ram': u'2048', u'host': u'9fa544f5c47569db21d50bc6c0765296316a56bd6baf6b04d705686a', u'flavor.ephemeral': u'0', u'image.name': u'ubuntu-io', u'image_ref_url': u'link': u"[{'href': 'link', 'rel': 'bookmark'}]", u'cpu_number': u'1', u'flavor.disk': u'20', u'root_gb': u'20', u'name': u'instance-000000d3', u'memory_mb': u'2048', u'instance_type': u'596642d8-0813-4ae9-aec4-0105fdf05761', u'vcpus': u'1', u'image_ref': u'5776a360-0953-4c93-931d-a6e3616fb8dc', u'flavor.links': u"[{'href': 'link', 'rel': 'bookmark'}]"}, u'source': u'openstack', u'counter_unit': u'%', u'recorded_at': u'2015-07-01T15:13:56.006000', u'project_id': u'1670f0e56fb6421cb83d81b60b149c04', u'message_id': u'ca8ea466-2003-11e5-a764-002590e64886', u'counter_type': u'gauge'}>, <OldSample {u'counter_name': u'cpu_util', u'user_id': u'7bffa12f482840c7801e3e01e160c8cb', u'resource_id': u'0c8b6b26-3340-41e3-ac8b-cc38f15d3570', u'timestamp': u'2015-07-01T15:08:32', u'counter_volume': 5.4399999999999995, u'resource_metadata': {u'ramdisk_id': u'None', u'flavor.vcpus': u'1', u'OS-EXT-AZ.availability_zone': u'nova', u'display_name': u'kalman_instance', u'flavor.id': u'1', u'status': u'active', u'ephemeral_gb': u'0', u'flavor.name': u'm1.tiny', u'disk_gb': u'1', u'kernel_id': u'None', u'image.id': u'1c9b08f0-d1fa-4acc-a11c-87b77310158c', u'flavor.ram': u'512', u'host': u'25aa71ded460ea9d4bf52e1aac34017691699cb5e4e389704d738bed', u'flavor.ephemeral': u'0', u'image.name': u'cirros', u'image_ref_url': u'http://192.168.26.1:8774/d1d65b6feab741a6a2905e6197cb15ee/images/1c9b08f0-d1fa-4acc-a11c-87b77310158c', u'image.links': u"[{'href': 'http://192.168.26.1:8774/d1d65b6feab741a6a2905e6197cb15ee/images/1c9b08f0-d1fa-4acc-a11c-87b77310158c', 'rel': 'bookmark'}]", u'cpu_number': u'1', u'flavor.disk': u'1', u'root_gb': u'1', u'name': u'instance-0000013c', u'memory_mb': u'512', u'instance_type': u'1', u'vcpus': u'1', u'image_ref': u'1c9b08f0-d1fa-4acc-a11c-87b77310158c', u'flavor.links': u"[{'href': 'http://192.168.26.1:8774/d1d65b6feab741a6a2905e6197cb15ee/flavors/1', 'rel': 'bookmark'}]"}, u'source': u'openstack', u'counter_unit': u'%', u'recorded_at': u'2015-07-01T15:08:32.459000', u'project_id': u'1670f0e56fb6421cb83d81b60b149c04', u'message_id': u'09b5173e-2003-11e5-ac7a-002590e64b12', u'counter_type': u'gauge'}>]
```

Comment: What does you current code do? What do you mean by `dataset` , what type is it?

Comment: The current code extracts data from source cleans it and sends back the values that I need. The data is json

Comment: Like I said what does `data_checkpoint_size` look like?

Comment: ah ok, edited my question you can see data_checkpoint_size there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make some corrections to your function:

```
def counterVolume(data_checkpoint_size):
    counter=0 
    for each in data_checkpoint_size:
        if each["checkpoint_size"]<checkpoint_size_limit:
            counter+=1
    return counter
```

Comment: Or - more succintly `return sum(1 for el in data_checkpoint_size if el['checkpoint_size'] < checkpoint_size_limit)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler version with `sum`, `map` and `lambda`

```
sum( 
    map(lambda data, checkpoint_size_limit=10000: 
            1 if data['checkpoint_size']<checkpoint_size_limit else 0
        , data_checkpoint_size
       ) 
)
```

- the lambda function checks for a condition and return 1 if the condition is true else 0.
- `map` applies the given function to all the elements of the list (`iterable`).
- `sum` of this gives the count of variables where condition was true.

Comment: using data['checkpoint_size'] raises following error: TypeError: 'OldSample' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: In my program I used `data` as dict. if in your program you have `data` as an object could use `data.checkpoint_size`

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
sum(d['checkpoint_size'] < checkpoint_size_limit for d in data_checkpoint_size)
```

Sums a list of booleans. During casting to number, `True` is resolved to 1 and `False` to 0.

Comment: nice and correct, but it sums the zeroes as well. See @Jon Clements' solution in the comment to the first answer. His approach only sums the ones.

Comment: @Pynchia could you clarify? "Correct, but..." seems like contradiction to me.

Comment: it is correct, since it gives the expected result. And it provides extra info on casting booleans, which is helpful. But it collects and sums elements that can be left out. Nothing too bad, but since your solution is quite similar to the one I mentioned, I thought to point out the difference. Not to tell you off, but to clarify how they differ.